# how to assign resx resource to itemtemplate control

Tags: xaml, localization, windows-phone, datatemplate

In my WP8 app, i have radio button where customized it through datatemplate and embedded a textblock in it. My question is how to assign a key from my resx resource file to assign text value, so that i can localize these datatemplate control names without any issues.

Below is my sample xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblTileColor" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Themes_Tile_label, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />

<RadioButton x:Name="accentColor" GroupName="tileColor" IsChecked="true">
                    <RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Rectangle Width="25" Height="25" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                <TextBlock Width="10"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="lblDefaultAccent" Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.Themes_Tile_Default, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                </RadioButton>
```

Here i am trying to assign Themes_Tile_Default resx key to textblock named lblDefaultAccent control. 
With above code i am seeing xaml error (i.e. Invalid XAML) in Datatemplate section - if i assign text value directly with hardcoding it is working...

any help to resolve this?

Comment: Do you a LocalizedStrings class in your project?

Comment: yes, i have this class for accessing resources from resx.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Are you able to build your project?

Comment: no, i am seeing the "Invalid XAML" error when i build the project...

Comment: Check the error list, there must be some other error causing this.

Comment: after clean and rebuild error disappeared. sorry for the false alarm :)